# positive semidefinite matrix condition

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, sp.spectral-theory, laplacian, semidefinite-programming

There is a [great work](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/0805002) of Alizadeh that in section 4 speaks about Minimizing sum of the first few(k-largest) eigenvalues of a symmetric matrix. Instead of a symmetric model we use the weighted Laplacian $(L_c(G) = \displaystyle \sum_{ij \in E} c_{ij}E_{ij})$of graph $G = (N, E)$. Then the dual problem is the following model:

\begin{equation*}
\begin{array}{llll}
 \min & k z + {\rm trace~}V \\
 \rm{s.t.} & Iz  + V - \sum_{ij \in E} c_{ij}E_{ij} \succeq 0 , \\ % U
      & \sum_{ij \in E} c_{ij} = 1 ,\\ % V
      & c \geq 0, ~ V \succeq 0 .
\end{array}
\end{equation*}

Again, we write the dual of the above model to obtain this model:

\begin{equation*}
\begin{array}{llll}
 \max & x\\
 \rm{s.t.}  & {\rm trace~} Y = k, \\
      &  x  \leq \langle E_{ij}, Y \rangle  ~~~~ \textrm{for } ij \in E,\\
      & 0 \preceq Y \preceq I.
\end{array}
\end{equation*}

Because $Y$ is a positive semidefinite matrix, i.e., $Y \succeq 0$, one property of such a matrices allows us to use the Gram representation: $Y = V^T V$ with $V \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$. If $v_i$ denotes the $i$-th column of $V$ then how can one write 
condition $Y \preceq I$ in terms of $v_i$ which $I$ is identity matrix with all diagonal entries equal to $1$?

For example the gram representation of first constraint is:
$${\rm trace~} Y = \sum_{i \in N} \| v_i \|^2 = k$$

Comment: Where does this question come from? It looks like homework to me.

Comment: @IgorRivin this is a part of an sdp optimization model and I could not figure out this constraint. It is from Alizadeh's paper(famous work) in sdp.

Comment: OK, fair enough. You might want to put the "back story" in the question in the future...

Comment: @IgorRivin : I have edited and explained in more details.

Answer (score 2):

Probably you are looking for the following (Schur-complements lemma):

\begin{equation*}
  V^TV = Y \preceq I,\quad\leftrightarrow\quad \begin{bmatrix} I & V^T\\ V & I \end{bmatrix} \succeq 0.
\end{equation*}

Comment: @suvrit: Now, do you think with new explanation your suggestion will work?

Comment: I don't really understand what you're getting at. I could write your constraint as $\|V^TV\| \le 1$, which is a difficult nonlinear constraint, which you can then write it terms of singular values of $V$, but one doesn't gain much by that...

Comment: I want to have an embedding model in terms of column of $V$, i.e. $v_i$'s.